# modify active record relation in ruby

Tags: ruby, json, controller, split

I have my @albums which are working fine; pickung data up with albums.json.
What I'd like to do is to split this @albums in three parts.
I was thinking of something like { "ownAlbums" : [ ... ], "friendSubscriptions" : [ ... ], "otherSubscriptions" : [ ... ] } But I got several errors like

```
syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting kEND @albums["own"] => @albums
```

when I tried

```
@albums["own"] => @albums
```

or

```
TypeError (Symbol as array index):
```

when I tried:

```
@albums[:otherSubscriptions] = 'others'
```

and so on.
I never tried something like this before but this .json is just a simple array ?
How can I split it in three parts ?
Or do I have to modify the active record to do so ? Because if so, I'd find another way than splitting.

**Second Edit**
I tried something like this and it's actually working:

```
@albums = [*@albums]
own = []
cnt = 0
@albums.each do |ownAlbum|
cnt = cnt.to_int
  own[cnt] = ownAlbum
  cnt=cnt+1
end

subs = Subscription.where(:user_id => @user.user_id)

@albums[0] = own
@albums[1] = subs
```

But where I have [0] and [1] I'D prefer Strings.
But then I get the error: TypeError (can't convert String into Integer):

How to get around that ?

Comment: Could you add the code you are using to "split" this `@albums` array ?  If you do not have one, of course the code your wrote is not working, please give us information about how you would to split it ? I guess it will depend of some fields of each array ? Also the part about the `.json` is not clear..

Comment: I'll edit it to the question